# How to check the numeric timezone difference between GMT in OS X terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal

Is there a way to check which numeric timezone (i.e. difference from UTC) I'm currently in using the OS X terminal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can by running the `date` command:

```
date +%z
```

The `%z` equates to the time zone offset value as explained on [this detailed man page for `strftime`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/strftime.3.html) that contains date and time format information:

> `%z` is replaced by the time zone offset from UTC; a leading plus sign stands for east of UTC, a minus sign for west of UTC, hours and minutes follow with two digits each and no delimiter between them (common form for RFC 822 date headers).

If you want the time zone name, you can use `date +%Z`.